# Страница из кэша сервера не отдается браузерам

Tags: php, apache, сервер, кэширование

Есть такая php-страница:

```
<? php
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/cache/exp.cache'))
{  
    readfile(__DIR__.'/cache/exp.cache'); 
    exit();
} 
ob_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html> .............// тут html-код...</html>

    <?php  
$buffer = ob_get_contents(); 

$fp = fopen(__DIR__.'/cache/exp.cache', 'w'); 

fwrite($fp, $buffer);
ob_end_flush(); 

fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Этот код, вроде бы, должен:

1) проверять, есть ли страница exp.cache в директории cache,

2) если есть, то загружать ее из этой папки cache,

3) если нет, то формировать страницу из кода, который следует далее.

Но почему-то из этого файла /cache/exp.cache страница не загружается. Или загружается от случая к случаю. Несмотря на то, что она существует, в браузере я зачастую получаю 404, если предварительно очистила кэш браузера.

А иногда нормально загружается.

Подскажите, что я сделала неправильно?
Сервер - Apache

Я хочу, чтобы данные из БД, которые идут далее на этой странице, формировались только 1 раз для первого посетителя за период. А все последующие пользователи получали страницу из кэша сервера.
Спасибо!

P.S. В журнале ошибок на хостинге вижу вот что:

> 2019/03/13 00:22:39 [warn] 2303163#2303163: *10757694 an upstream
>   response is buffered to a temporary file
>   /var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp/5/71/0000002715 while reading upstream,
>   client: 32.140.71.229, server: site.ru, request: "GET /exp.php
>   HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/exp.php", host: "site.ru"

Меня крайне смущает это: nginx при том, что сервер-то на хостинге apache.

Comment: `Или загружается от случая к случаю.` - вот это интересно. `в браузере я зачастую получаю 404, если предварительно очистила кэш браузера` - а вот это немного пролило свет. каким способом создается страница `__DIR__.'/cache/exp.cache'` ?

Comment: Total, я дополнила вопрос полным кодом (без хтмл).

Comment: Данный кусок кода полностью рабочий и не приводит к описываемым аномалиям. Проблему я вижу в каких-то других местах. Например, другой скрипт пишет в `__DIR__.'/cache/exp.cache'` пусто содержимое. Файл продолжает существовать и быть пустым. `в браузере я зачастую получаю 404, если предварительно очистила кэш браузера` - а это значит, что также если клиентское кеширование (в браузере). временно выключите кеширование браузером любым способом, чтобы оно не мешало отлаживаться.

Comment: а как вы рефрешите это кэш? по крону (или еще как-то по событию?) что ли удаляете файл? мб проще вообще на уровне хтаксесса выдавать кэшированный вместо скрипта, если он имеется?

Comment: teran, пока в процессе отладки я его удаляю при необходимости. хтаксесс тут не подойдет, у меня кэшируются результаты запросов к БД, которая обновляется 6 раз в день. И нужно удалять кэш после каждого обновления базы.

Comment: Total, в этудиректорию пишет только один скрипт. И это пока елинственное, что может быть туда записано.

Comment: дак и удаляйте кэш, при чем тут хтаксесс? Задача хтаксесса проверить, есть ли файла кэша, и если есть выдать его. а если нет, передать управление в индекс ваш. К механизму удаления кэша это отношения не имеет. В принципе нет особого смысла читать и отдавать через пхп то, что может быть отдано напрямую сервером, коли страница у вас туда записывается целиком.

Comment: в любом случае посмотрите логи доступа и ошибок сервера, да и пхп заодно. мб что-то там найдется. здесь пока что не видно причин для выдачи 404.

Comment: Приложила лог ошибки. Объясните, что это значит?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, я слегка лоханулась, пытаясь определить, откуда загружается страница: из кэша сервера или из файловой директории сервера.

Меня вел в заблуждение джентльменский набор из кэша сервера + кэша браузера.

Отключила кэш браузера по совету Total Pusher + изменила title страницы exp.php
И к счастью своему вижу в браузере старый title, то есть, загружаемый из кэша сервера.

То есть именно тот результат, который мне нужен.
Спасибо!